# Can "information commons" be translated as information repository?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The reader may find some redundancy between the introductory section and the 
>   subsequent chapters on Locke, copyright protection, or the information commons in Section II and Section III.  (Spinello, Richard, & Tavani, Herman, Intellectual Property Rights in a Networked World:Theory and Practice, p. X)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_commons) defines the term as an information system. Do I get it right if I assume it refers to an information inventory (repository)? I need to know this as I have to translate it as accurate as I can into the destination language.

Comment: Besides your question about the definition of "information repository," I am not sure the original sentence is clearly stated. By the way it's worded, it is not clear what the "subsequent chapters" are about. I have a feeling the original sentence is poorly worded.

Answer (score 3):

The term "commons" comes from the Middle Ages and referred to the land or common grounds that villagers shared for collective needs such as grazing their animals.

The **information commons** can be roughly defined as an open online space which is collectively built and where information and knowledge is freely shared. ([Source](http://www.apc.org/en/node/8626/))

*You may reword the expression as "publicly and freely shared information"*.